# Convert array to object list in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a function that can convert an array `['A', 'B', 'C']` to an object array `[{name: 'A'}, {name: 'B'}, {name: 'C'}]`?

Or do I need to write a util function? It is no big deal to write one but curious if a well known function is already there.

Thanks

Comment: simple map loop

Comment: You can use `map` like this `arr.map(name => ({name}))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.map().  Array.map is a method that will iterate through each element in an Array and return an output based on the callback.  You can find more information on Array.map on the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map

And here is a working example: https://jsbin.com/qawener/edit?js,console

In this example, we take each element of the array and we return an object with {"name": }.  This then creates the newArray array that will have `[{name: 'A'}, {name: 'B'}, {name: 'C'}]`.

```
const originalArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

let newArray = originalArray.map(element => { return {name: element}; });


console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Map works very well for these types of situations.

```
const array = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
const myNewArray = array.map(function(map, i) {
     const dict = {"name":array[i]}    
     return dict;
}, {});

console.log(myNewArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the given answer, you may use [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the object.

```js
const
    names = ["a", "b", "c"],
    result = names.map(name => ({ name }));

console.log(result);
```